# Target multiple CSS classes with and/or

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there any way to target elements that must have class A, and can then have either class B or C or D or F...etc?
Class A is required, followed by one of the others. I don't want to have to repeat almost the same code for each, as there are quite a few in my css file.

I have been playing around with attribute selectors but can't figure it out, was hoping I'm overlooking something.

Comment: You could probably do something with a little JS to add a class to things that match a specific criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old way:

```css
.a.b, .a.c, .a.d, .a.e, .a.f
```

The proposed way (that few current browsers support)

```css
.a:matches(.b, .c, .d, .e, .f)
```

Some browsers implement it as

```css
.a:moz-any(.b, .c, .d, .e, .f)
.a:webkit-any(.b, .c, .d, .e, .f)
```

See [MDN - The `:any` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any)

Comment: I think Safari supports :matches(), great article on [webkit blog](https://webkit.org/blog/3615/css-selectors-inside-selectors-discover-matches-not-and-nth-child/).

Comment: this is exactly what i am looking for, but if i have to use browser prefixes, then i am still going to have to repeat myself 3 times.... so same as just chaining them as the old way...... or?

Comment: [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Amatches) results of which browsers support `:matches()` and how.

Comment: @TylerH wow, thats no good support. I was hoping it was this one: http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchesselector

Comment: @FrankUnderwood Nope, that's for when you're interacting with the DOM, via JS or some other method, unfortunately.

Comment: @TylerH  Right, so no IE support what so ever, no prefix etc.... makes this solution unusable for me. too bad, would bee good

Comment: @Frank Underwood: Yeah pretty much. Don't bother with :any(), no matter what anyone else tells you. *They were never intended for production use.*

Comment: @BoltClock ok, well then its back to chaining. Will accept this answer as it is correct, just doesnt fit my code.